# Any way of disambiguation within lambdas or function composition (without intermediate function)?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
data Human = Human {name :: String } deriving (Show , Eq)
data Dog = Dog {name :: String } deriving (Show , Eq)

humans = [Human "bob" , Human "john", Human "paul"]

-- Working
humanName h = name (h :: Human)
fh = filter ( (=="bob").humanName ) humans  
fh' = filter (\h -> (humanName h )=="bob"  ) humans  

-- Ambigous, not compiling
fh2 = filter ( (=="bob").name ) humans
-- Ambigous, not compiling
fh3 = filter (\h -> (name h )=="bob"  ) humans

-- Not compiling, I don't know if it's an error syntax or if this is impossible
fh4 = filter (\h -> (name h)=="bob" (h :: Human) ) humans
```

Is there any way to have fh2, fh3 or fh4 working without having to define a named function for disambiguation ?

Comment: You can use `\(Human n) -> n == "bob"` If I understand it correctly, but your `fh4` is syntactically invalid.

Comment: What about `fh3 = filter (\h -> (name (h::Human) )=="bob") humans` ?

Comment: I will edit my question; as indeed the idea is that there is off course much more fields in each data Types and I can not use the (==) directly on the type but must use the name function of them

Comment: @sandwood: is there a particular reason why you use the `DuplicateRecordFields` extension, and not declare records with `humanName`, `dogName`, etc.?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : yes, I made really a mcve stripping off the whole picture  : short : I made some kind of Database Tables to Haskell Data type  (  haskell generated code based on the actual database, mapping a table to a Haskell Data Type with one record per database column). In this database I have hundred of tables, and as you can imagine I have several of them with the same column name (says, "id", "name", ...).  
I do not want to prefix all of them with the table name as I want to keep it simple and closest to the  real column name in the DB

Comment: Do you mean `name (h :: Human) == "bob"`? That's valid if I remember correctly.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent : thanks, that is what I was looking for. put it as an  Answer so that I can validate. Btw any way of doing this directly in a function  composition ?

Comment: @sandwood: I think you solve the problem here at the wrong level, you can - given you use a good library - specify that the database column is different than the attribute of the Haskell record.

Comment: I have converted my comment to an answer. But I'm not sure to understand your other question. Defining `humanName` as you did is not a bad idea IMHO.

Comment: Also see my edit.  Defining a class is convenient in such circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `name` is a duplicated record field you need to specify which type it is applied to:

```
fh3 = filter (\h -> (name (h::Human))=="bob") humans
```

See [DuplicateRecordFields](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields) for more info.

### Edit

Otherwise, when dealing with duplicated record fields I like to proceed as follows.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
data Human = Human {_name :: String } deriving (Show , Eq)
data Dog = Dog {_name :: String } deriving (Show , Eq)

class HasName a where 
    name :: a -> String

instance HasName Human where
    name = _name

instance HasName Dog where
    name = _name
```

Then you can do

```
filter (\h -> (name h == "bob")) humans
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @StéphaneLaurent's answer, using [`TypeApplication`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication) can help with point-free style:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-} 
data Human = Human {_name :: String } deriving (Show , Eq)
data Dog = Dog {_name :: String } deriving (Show , Eq)

class HasName a where 
    name :: a -> String

instance HasName Human where
    name = _name

instance HasName Dog where
    name = _name

humans = [Human "bob" , Human "john", Human "paul"]

-- Now you can write it in pointfree style:
fh2 = filter ((=="Bob") . name @Human) humans
--                             ^^^^^^ This is a type argument!
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a type signature for all these functions? like:

```
fh :: [Human] -> [Human]
```

Adding a type signature should force the compiler to select the correct version.